# IE plugin (Not verified)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, plugins, activex

I created a plugin for Internet Explorer (ActiveX object) and installed it successfully, but in browser it appear in front of the name (not verified).

Here are the registry values:

```
string buttonPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions\" + t.GUID.ToString("B");

                RegistryKey But= Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(buttonPath);
                But.SetValue("ButtonText", "****");
                But.SetValue("Default Visible", "Yes");
                But.SetValue("Icon", "C:\\BB.ico");
                But.SetValue("HotIcon", "C:\\bB.ico");
                But.SetValue("CLSID", "{1FBA04EE-3024-11D2-8F1F-0000F87ABD16}");
                But.SetValue("ClsidExtension", "{" + Guid + "}");
But.Close();
```

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sign it first。
1.get a cert
2.sign it
3.publish

Comment: Oh, can you tell me which CA do you use?

Comment: i use the solutions that came with VS2010. A ".pfx" file in my project

Comment: That's for development, and you can just use that plugin on your computer. If you want to publish your plugin, you'd better find a CA, buy a cert from the CA, sign your plugin, and publish. Then IE can verify your plugin through your CA.